# Patterns to organize overal architecture of single page application

Tags: model-view-controller, javascriptmvc, singlepage

Good day!

I'm getting started with client side MVC (looking on JavaScriptMVC, Knockout.js etc) and I have question about overal architecture. Say I have one-page application. It has a number of screens (for example, main, settings, user profile etc). As far as I understand each of these "screens" should be a separate M,V,C triad.

How to organize this screens? What lifecycle thay should have?

In server-side MVC we have a front-controller, URL routing etc. What will be the subsitution on the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For googlers :)

backbone.js has router built-in: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/

For standalone solution I've found this: http://sammyjs.org/